# Erlang home directory

Tags: erlang

Hi I have a command which starts an Erlang node (using run_erl program) and then I connect to it using to_erl program.
After connecting to the node I issue the following command to get the home dir.

```
init:get_argument(home).
```

And it returns "/" as the home directory, which I know it is definitely wrong.
What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know how you setup is so it is hard to analyse but the init:get_argument(home) call will return the value of the environment variable HOME (on any form of unix and it can be inspected by calling echo $HOME).

Comment: And is this possible to overwrite this variable before starting the Erlang node? I mean can I set it via a -home flag?

Comment: It depends on your operating system. On a unix style system calling export HOME=directory normally does the trick.

Comment: I tired that, but i still get an extra HOME variable with the value "/". Which i don't know where does this come from!